# AntiVirus ruined my Ethereum DB for Mist?

Tags: mist

Have been running Mist for a few months now and regularly installing the updates. On OSX. Currently on 0.7.2.

I had installed Avast AntiVirus and when I turned Mist on while this was downloading blocks, Avast saw them as a Virus. I stopped Mist and tried to tell it that these are OK. Ultimately, I removed Avast. I think however, I never put the quarantined blocks back and now when I start Mist I get errors like the below. What can I do? Or do I have to reinstall from scratch?

```
Fatal: blockchain db err: leveldb/table: corruption on table-footer (pos=1829964): bad magic number [file=170175.ldb]
```

and

```
...I0511 07:15:51.797087     621 database.go:71] Alloted 433MB cache to /Users/lukeollett/Library/Ethereum/chaindata
Fatal: blockchain db err: leveldb/table: corruption on table-footer (pos=1829964): bad magic number [file=170175.ldb]
```

Comment: I tried `geth updatedb` but was returned `Fatal: Could not open database: leveldb/table: corruption on table-footer (pos=1829964): bad magic number [file=170175.ldb]`

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer as correct by clicking the tick icon below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end after trying `geth updatedb` and `geth upgradedb` which oculd never connect to databse, I just removed the database `geth removedb` and reopened Mist and I am currently redownloading the block chain.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by

1. `geth removedb` (while the Mist application is not running!);
2. `geth --fast`.

I think the error occured because initially I was running removedb when the Mist application was running.